# Binary tree with powers of two

Tags: mathematics

Can you construct a 3-level [binary tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) with the values 1 to 7 such that the sum of values at any level is a distinct power of 2?

**Bonus:** Can you do this with any n-level binary tree with values 1 to $2^n-1$?

Comment: I support the bounty

Comment: Oh, so that's where that huge lump of rep came from. :-) Thanks, @msh210!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll go ahead and say

> ```
>       4
>      / \
>     2   6
>    /\   /\
>   1  3 5  7
> ```

Bonus:

Assume you can do this for $n$ layers containing $m = 2^n-1$ numbers. Then you can double each value in the solution for n, and add another layer below it. It will fit the rest of the numbers, of which there are $m+1$. Since the sum of all the numbers from 1 to $x$ is $T(x) = x(x+1)/2$, the numbers in the last row add up to

$$T(2m+1) - 2T(m)$$
$= (2m+1)(2m+2)/2 - 2m(m+1)/2$
$= (2(2m+1)(m+1) - 2m(m+1))/2$
$= (2(2m+1)-2m)(m+1))/2$
$= (2m+2)(m+1)/2$
$$= (m+1)^2 $$

which is clearly a power of two whenever $m$ is of the form $2^n-1$:
$$ ((2^n-1)+1)^2= (2^n)^2 = 2^{2n}$$

(Also, $2^{2n}$ is four times larger than the sum of the previous last row $2^{2(n-1)}$, which means it's larger than the sum of any other new row, guaranteeing distinctness)

This means that

> Since the solution of n=1 is trivial, we can use the method above to find a solution for any n. For example, n=4:
>
> ```
>                            2   (2)
>          1   (1)   -->    / \        -->
>                          1   3 (4)
>
>
>
>        4     (4)               8             (8)
>       / \                   /     \
>      2   6   (8)    -->    4       12       (16)
>     /\   /\               / \     /  \
>    1  3 5  7 (16)        2   6   10  14     (32)
>                         /\   /\  /\   /\
>                        1  3 5 7 9 11 13 15  (64)
> ```

This completes the solution.

As an interesting aside, because of the way we always placed the odd numbers in the bottom row in ascending order, we actually happened to create a

> [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), so reading the tree in the [LNR order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order,_LNR) (aka in-order, which is basically "from left to right, ignoring height"),

should get us back all the original numbers [in ascending order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort). This, then, gives us a nifty shortcut to construct a tree with the desired property for any n without going through any of the tedious recursive steps:

> Just draw the tree and fill in the nodes from left to right.

Comment: Correct. Excellent explanation and additional information.

Comment: Could there be any other solutions?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky of course, but they are limited to shuffling the numbers around; the level sums are fixed: The relevant triangular numbers T(2^n-1) are going to have exactly n 1-bits in their binary representation (because otherwise there couldn't be a solution for that n), and those 1-bits will be the leftmost ones, followed by n-1 zero-bits. Starting from root level (the level with only one node) of the tree, it's not difficult to see there's always only one way to assign those 1-bits to the tree levels.

Comment: There is aquick way to see each row sums to a power of 2.  Take for instance the 4-level example with 8 at the root.  You can replace each value in a row with the average of the row.  The average is always 8, a power of 2.  Multiplied by the number of elements in a row, also a power of 2, it gives a power of 2.  Of course this is only a sketch, it would require a more formal proof.  But to me it is already convincing.

Answer (score 2):

Another perspective:

> Suppose there are $n$ levels in the tree. Write the numbers 1, 2, …, $2^n - 1$ in binary and number the bits so that bit index 1 is the most-significant bit, bit index 1 is the second-most-significant bit, etc. Fill in the binary tree as follows: place all $2^{k-1}$ numbers that have bit index $k$ as their lowest bit set in level $k$ of the tree. For example, here’s the solution for $k=3$:
>  
>               `100`
>  
>              `/   \`
>  
>           `010     110`
>  
>           `/ \     / \`
>  
>         `001 011 101 111`
>
>  This is equivalent to @Bass’s inductive answer, except without requiring induction. Here’s the math that shows that it works.
>
>  Focus on row $k$, one-indexed, in a tree of $n$ rows. The numbers in this row all have bit index $k$ set to $1$, the bits after that set to zero, and all possible combinations of the previous $k-1$ bits present once. To add up these numbers, we need to account for adding up lots of copies of $2^{n-k}$ (representing the fact that the $k$th bit is set) and adding up all possible $(k-1)$-bit numbers, each scaled by $2^{n-k+1}$ (corresponding to the fact that those numbers appear in the high bits). This works out to
>
>  $$\begin{aligned}(1 + 2 + \dots + (2^{k-1}-1))\cdot 2^{n-k+1} + 2^{k-1} \cdot 2^{n-k} &= \frac{(2^{k-1} - 1) \cdot 2^{k-1} \cdot 2^{n-k+1}}{2} + 2^{n-1} \\ &= (2^{k-1} - 1) \cdot 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} \\ &= 2^{n + k - 2}\end{aligned}$$
>
>  So we see that row $k$ sums to $2^{n+k-2}$, meaning each row sums to a power of two and no two rows have the same sum.

Comment: It does require induction. Pretty much any proof that says "do this for n steps" requires induction, whether or not it makes that induction explicit.

Comment: Pretty nifty. Might use a word or three on showing why the powers of two reached this way are distinct.

Comment: @Bass Just added the math in. We can directly compute the sum of each row as a function of $n$ and the row number.